# Where to save my app Settings after I get it from sharedpref

Tags: android

In ym android app, I have Settings menu in which use sets their app mode, sound, music ...etc
I retreive/store this in from/in shared preferences.

My question is onceI retreive this info, where is the best place to store it to make accessible by my whole application?

So far what I do is I read it from my mian activityu and sent it as an Extra between activities but something is telling me it is not efficient/correct way. Should I store the info in the Application class so any activity can access it while the app is running

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just grab it from SharedPreferences every time you want the value? This saves you from having two copies of the same data in the application which could potentially get out of sync.

I'm assuming you don't need to poll these values thousands of time per second such that it would have any kind of meaningful performance impact.

Further reading:

[Don't Repeat Yourself - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: I will need to pull it 5 times a second.Isn't this too much ? (and adding the same code to every activity is cumbersom, right?

Comment: I doubt it would have any performance impact, and I don't believe it's more than a few lines of code to read from SharedPrefs. You could locally cache the value in each activity if you want, but I was suggesting to avoid two global stores of the same information. Android environment already provides you a global store of preferences, you don't need to duplicate it. @Snake

Answer (score 0):

You should create a static class named like **configuration.java**, where you can put all the configuration/setting.

Comment: I like this, but isn't this weak way of doing things! People always try to avoid static